# Nesting RecyclerView inside another Layout hides the list

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

From Android Studio 3.2.1 I created File->New->Fragment->Fragment (List) and it auto created a RecyclerView list, which works but if I try to nest the RecyclerView inside another layout it hides the list. I have tried everything to make it work but cannot get it to. I simply want to make an action bar below the list on the bottom of the screen.

As auto generated by Android Studio:

browse_recycler_view.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.hssw.hssw_petmatch.FragmentBrowse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".FragmentBrowse"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_browse_item"/>
```

FragmentBrowse.java:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(getArguments() != null)
            {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
            }
        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browse_recycler_view, container, false);
        // Set the adapter
        if(view instanceof RecyclerView)
            {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if(mColumnCount <= 1)
                {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                }
            else
                {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
                }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new BrowseRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS, mListener));
            }
        return view;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your RecyclerView inside Coordinator layout. like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.hssw.hssw_petmatch.FragmentBrowse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".FragmentBrowse"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_browse_item"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that works after modifying onCreateView by deleting "if(view instanceof RecyclerView)" and changing to "RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list)." I tried to nest it in a FrameLayout, which worked for another app of mine a few years ago. I guess things change...

Comment: @Samuel nice to hear you solved it. Please upvote this answer if this help for u.